What is the correct way to receive a lambda with capture in a function argument?
In freestanding environment without standard library I use:
template <typename Func> 
auto for_each_until_false(Func func) const -> void {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        if (!func(data[i])) {
            return;
        }
    }
}

Are there drawbacks concerning the generated code by the template?
Is it one function generated for every calling site?
Do compilers optimize this?

It's implementation (compiler/toolchain) dependent.  The only way to know is to test and profile - for each toolchain/platform/etc you use (examine the code produced to see if there is any duplication in the final executable, measure to determine if there is an unacceptable run-time (performance) impact, etc etc).

you are asking about specifics of compiler and target architeture, but you do not say what you use. Asking for all is too broad. The standard does not mandate this to be opimitzed. On the other hand there is no obvious reason why the instantitation cannot be inlined on each call site

With the mainstream compilers (gcc, clang, MSVC) this style is considered OK and will be optimized properly. But we can only guess what your specific compiler will do with it.

any simple example might be too simplified so that the compiler can do more optimizations then in a real case or it might be too articifially crafted to prevent optimizations. You need to profile and look what the compiler does in your real code

what is object_id, len and data ? There is discrepancy between the level of detail you ask for and the lack of details you provide. I think all one can say with certainty is that your way of passing a callable is "ok"

The generalized question is how to pass lambdas that captures to a function when operating in freestanding environment without libraries.Passing a lambda that does not capture can be done by accepting a function pointer such as auto apply_on_chars_from_cursor_to_end(void (*f)(char)) const -> void. However a lambda that captures has a context. What is the recommended way to do that?

Pass func by reference so as to avoid the copy overhead of a lambda and the by-value captures it might be holding.
Instead of this:
template <typename Func>
auto for_each_until_false(Func func) const -> void {

Use this:
template <typename Func>
auto for_each_until_false(Func& func) const -> void {


If you take in the parameter by reference then you should use a forwarding reference instead (Func&& or auto&&). You can't pass in an inlined lambda by lvalue reference, eg: for_each_until_false([](int value){ ... }) would fail to compile with your suggestion, but works fine with mine.

I tried auto, auto const & and auto &&. All generate the same binary size with riscv32-unknown-elf-g++. Any drawbacks with auto && instead of simply auto?

@user529327 - it doesn't necessarily influence binary size. Just overall runtime performance.  Kind of like passing a large struct by value vs reference.

That part I understand. I also understand that auto & binds to a named something while auto && binds to anything, including a temporary expression.
My question drifts away towards a C++ question. Why is it not always auto && instead of auto &? Is auto && C++ way of saying auto & had some limitations. Use auto && always instead.
